# realtime checking sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to build code that pops up information when mouse leaves the browser. I got it working as far as alert is popping up and session information is stored but only after I refresh the browser.

```
var key = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'));
if (key.name != 'key') {
    $('body').mouseleave(function() {
        alert('Success');
        sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify( {name: 'key'} ));
    }); 
}
```

I want to build it as simple as possible. How I see it: if session is not set, show alert on mouseleave event. How to make that code to check in realtime if session is set?

Comment: Using _"real-time"_ and _"jQuery"_ in one sentence, bold move, let's see how it plays out.

Comment: As you can guess, I had a big problem to even try to explain what I want. So realtime seemed like a good word for that. It seems that I was wrong.

Comment: Sorry, it was a joke, I hope you didn't take it personally.

Answer (score 2):

You're only adding the `sessionStorage` when the user first leaves the page. Meaning, until the `mouseleave` event is fired the session key never gets set.

Let the event fire every time and change functionality based on the `sessionStorage` data

I pasted your code without the if check and it works:

```
$('body').mouseleave(function() {
     var data = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'));
     if(data) {
         console.log('Has Key... ');
     } else {
         sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify( {name: 'key'} ));
         console.log('Add Key... ');
     }
});
```

**Note:** Make sure you don't have the key already in your session from previous testing. `removeItem` each time prior to refresh of page.

Comment: Didnt work for me. It still shows again and again. I want to create something like in this page: http://220.lv, when you leave the page, you get popup

Comment: Updated the code that works for me. If that doesn't work, you might have another issue then what you're showing us.

Answer (score 0):

Please set session like this

```
 var key = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'));
    if (key) {
            $('body').mouseleave(function() {
            alert('Success');
            sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify( {name: 'key'} ));
        }); 
    }
```

it is working code. It would be better that if you check condition in mouseleave callback function like

```
 var key = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('data'));
  $('body').mouseleave(function() {
        if (key) {
            alert('Success');
           sessionStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify( {name: 'key'} ));
            }
      });
```